# DBT insert row without creating new table [Snowflake]

Tags: sql, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm using DBT and I want to insert rows in a table. My code works in Snowflake:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental'
    )
}}

INSERT INTO  {{ ref('gld__pnl')}} (region, period, COST, billable,record_type)
WITH AUTRE_CHAGE AS 
(
    SELECT * exclude(netvalue), sum(netvalue) as netvalue

    FROM {{ ref('gld__payable_invoice')}}
    where status ='Complete' 
        and PSA = TRUE 
        and RECHARGE_CUSTOMER=TRUE
    group by region, period,psa,recharge_customer,status
)
SELECT  AC.region, AC.period, AC.netvalue, 'TRUE','COST Adjustment'
FROM AUTRE_CHAGE AC
```

The lineage:

[image]

However when I'm running it on dbt cloud  I get the following error (but the preview works):

```
create or replace transient table REPORTING_FF_DEV.DBT_GOLD.gld__pnl_add_other_cost  as
        (

INSERT INTO  REPORTING_FF_DEV.DBT_GOLD.PNL_TABLE (region, period, COST, billable,record_type)
WITH AUTRE_CHARGE AS 
(
    SELECT * exclude(netvalue), sum(netvalue) as netvalue

    FROM REPORTING_FF_DEV.DBT_GOLD.OTHER_COST
    where status ='Complete' 
        and PSA = TRUE 
        and RECHARGE_CUSTOMER=TRUE
    group by region, period,psa,recharge_customer,status
)
SELECT  AC.region, AC.period, AC.netvalue, 'TRUE','COST Adjustment'
FROM AUTRE_CHARGE AC
        );
15:52:08  Opening a new connection, currently in state closed
15:52:09  Snowflake adapter: Snowflake error: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'INSERT'.
syntax error line 5 at position 0 unexpected 'WITH'.
```

But I don't want to create a new table, i change the config for this purpose. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

1. change the file name to match your table name - I guess the table is called gld__pnl and the model file gld__pnl_add_other_cost, that's why dbt "thinks" it is a different table, and tries to create one
2. Remove the INSERT INTO line, and let dbt do the magic

Comment: I can't rename my file to match the table, the name is already taken to create the table gld__pnl. If I remove the line insert into how to do specify in which the column will be insert ?